# Connect C# WinForms to MySQL Web Host

Tags: c#

I have a website that is connected to web host. I also have c# winforms and I want that to connect to web host used for login and other things.

Comment: Do you want to connect to database ?

Comment: @MirkoAcimovic Yes. @Jake you must be clear in which you want to login through your `website API` or the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

Web application is one type of application that communicate via HTTP protocol. Therefore, web application can use database and web services (WebAPI & WCF usually) this way.
Winforms (desktop application) is different type of application that can communicate with web services to access database and logic or directly to MySQL datbase. 
Receiving HTTP messages can be done but it is not sensible way. I assume you are interested in data and services that should be in Web service and that can communicate to database. There is a little use of HTML in winforms application.

So,

- If you want to connect to MySql database directly for data you can do it simple with connection string (that is pointing to your server IP or name on network:

  ```
  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;

  string myConnectionString;

  myConnectionString = "server=198.23.0.1;uid=root;pwd=12345; database=test";

  try
  {
      conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
      conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
      conn.Open();
  }
  catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
  {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
  ```

  - If you want to connect to web service that is running on your web server you will have to create a reference to that service. It's a bit longer subject so here is useful link : 
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-to-a-web-service-using-the-windows-forms-bindingsource
  - If you want to develop low level communication with your server via TCP/IP or UDP protocols, that can be done also but you will have to develop some additional logic and checks.

In a nutshell, it is possible to connect to MySQL database on remote machine just by connection string, also it is possible to connect to web service via Winforms by adding a reference to it, and it is possible to establish low level connection with your server (which is most error prone and not trivial task). Depends what are your needs.